# Trouble understanding Banach limit in Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology, limits, banach-spaces

Trouble understanding Banach limit in Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{N}$.
For example, if I have a series $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in [0,1]$, what does it mean that the limit of the series is $a(l)$ for $l \in \beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$? Why is this limit monotone and linear (it can't be just from definition can it?)

Comment: The Banach limit is an extension (using Hahn-Banach) of the functional $\lim :l_{0}\subset l^{\infty }\to \mathbb R$ to all of $l^{\infty }$. The idea is that the extension covers the non-convergent sequence case. Note that The space $\beta \omega $ contains no non-trivial convergent sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linearity of the limit means the following:
for every $l$ from βN∖N, and for every two sequences ($a_n$),($b_n$) and their continuous completion over βN ($A$),($B$)
B-lim (A+B)($l$) = B-lim A($l$) + B-lim B($l$)

Comment: What is your question? You should properly define the terms in your question and give some indication of what you have tried and what you are having difficulty with.